# how to get the selected checkbox values in cell of ui-grid using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, gridview, angular-ui-grid, checkboxlist

I have `UI-grid` build in `angularjs` in which cell template I have used check boxes.When i click on particular checkbox I want to get that checked box value,means I have table like structure and in table cell I have checkbox.And now I want to get the selected check box value.

Here is my code

```
$scope.gridOptionsNew = {
appScopeProvider : $scope,
columnDefs : [{
        enableCellEdit : false,
        field : 'SponsorType',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_SPONSOR_TYPE

    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'Hoarding',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_HOARDING,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    },
    {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'Print',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_PRINT,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'Radio',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_RADIO,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'StageBackDrops',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_STAGE_BACK_DROP,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'Stalls',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_STALLS,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'Banners',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_TABLE_BANNERS,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'Seats',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_SEATS,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'VenueBanners',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_VENUE_BRANDING,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }, {
        //enableCellEdit: true,
        field : 'StagePresence',
        displayName : me.labelText.ADD_STORY_STAGE_PRESENCE,
        cellTemplate : '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ' +
        'name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
    }
]}

$scope.yourMethod = function (radio) {
  console.log("value", radio);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try as shown below.

**set grid options like :**

```
 $scope.gridOptionsNew = { 
         appScopeProvider: $scope,
         //your other options
```

**then template :**

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" '+
name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity.Radio)"/></div>'
```

**Method :**

```
     //your Method
      $scope.yourMethod = function (radio) {

        //your logic
      };
```

**Update :**

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" '+
name="radio" value="radio" ng-click="grid.appScope.yourMethod(row.entity)"/></div>'
```

Comment: hello thank you so much for your answer. i just did console the value of radio in the function but is showing undefined.i did this           
            $scope.yourMethod = function (radio) {
             console.log("hello",radio);

              }; it is showing "" infront of hello

Comment: can you put your latest code snippets on your post above ?

Comment: Please see the `Update` section.Try like that and see the value using debug..Just debug using `F10`.